# Записать число в файл и считать его обратно

Tags: java

Ни как не могу выполнить простую операцию. Есть текстовый файл с числом integer, я пытаюсь это число считать, обработать и вернуть его обратно в этот же файл. Но почему то не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста, где моя ошибка?

text до выполнения:

```
    123456
```

```
    package org.example;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;

public class Main {

    static int number = 0;
    static int numbernext = 0;
    Integer send = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/text.txt"));
        writer.write(number);
        writer.close();
        System.out.println(number);

        System.out.println("--------------------");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/text.txt"));
        reader.read(CharBuffer.allocate(numbernext));
        reader.close();

        System.out.println(numbernext);

    }


}
```

text file после выполнения:

[image: TextTest]

консоль:

[image: ConsolTest]

Comment: static int number = 0;
    А вас тут ничего не смущает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При записи литерал, лучше явго привести к строке

```
writer.write(Integer.toString(number));
```

В противном случае `Writer` сочтёт, что Вы передали ему `char` и запишет в файл соответствующий данному числу симвлол. Например, если число будет `123`, то он запишет в файл символ "`{`"

Считывать легче построчно

```
reader.readLine()
```

А потом строку распарсить или другим способом привести к целочисленному виду

```
numbernext = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
```

**В итоге:**

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    static int number = 123123;
    static int numbernext = 0;
    Integer send = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/text.txt"));
        writer.write(Integer.toString(number));
        writer.close();
        System.out.println(number);

        System.out.println("--------------------");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/text.txt"));
        numbernext = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(numbernext);
    }
}
```

output:

```
123123
--------------------
123123
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Оно работает. Я уже подумал, может средства не те выбрал, но все хорошо.

Comment: @bodrovdeni, а я и забыл про ваше существование...хотел как-то посмотреть ваши вопросы и ответить на них но что-то времени не было особо.

Comment: ничего страшного, пока все потихоньку идет. Изучаю JAVA, изучаю Intellij Idea, пока все получается, медленно но получается. Вы и так меня много чему научили.

Comment: Смысл было все это расписывать , если человек банально вместо нужного значения записал 0 и прочитал тот же 0.

    static int number = 0;
    static int numbernext = 0;

Comment: @ScruffytheJanitor, а смысл, мой друг, очень прост. Потому что если `number` будет равен `45674567` - ничего не изменится и если не привести литерал к строке то он не будет корректно записывать это число в файл, так как он будет ассоциировать данное число с типом `char` и запишет в файл соответствующий символ(`` в данном случае), а если не применить вторую правку, то все что считает код из файла - это также один символ(даже если это число сильно его превосходит)...смысл в том, что в данном коде было две ошибки, которые были исправлены и которые были описаны в ответе.